# Who was the first to understand that there is not a net flux of energy between Sun and Earth, but of entropy?

Tags: biology, physicists, thermodynamics, earth-sciences

According to Penrose's *Cycles of Time*, he starts by reminding the usefulness of the second law of thermodynamics and how it applies to everyday life. In particular, how the net energy of Earth is a constant as the net flux of energy from the Sun into Earth is roughly 0 (most of the received energy is reemitted into space). However the flux emitted by the Earth into space is low energy photons and high entropy radiation compared to the one incoming from the Sun. The Sun then is a source with low entropy and that's what matters for biological processes on Earth. See also [recent Veritasium video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DxL2HoqLbyA&ab_channel=Veritasium).

Who was the first to notice this (publish about it)? Or in which time period this concept started being discussed and popularised? It would probably had been somebody from the 20th century as this concept needs understanding of blackbody and thermal radiation.

It reminds me of Schrödinger's *What is Life?* which discussed the importance of (lower) entropy in living beings.

Comment: I'd tweak the title wording to reflect the fact that the sun also emits energy, it just does not transfer a net amount to the earth. Clausius and Gibbs were in no doubt on this, and possibly others. Have you gone through Clausius' writings?

Comment: @CosmasZachos I did not consider Clausius because I do not think he might have that much to say about thermal radiation, he died when we were starting to understand it.

Comment: But the sun is not special, thermodynamically.  Just like Carnot, he was studying "useful" energy transfers... He might not be thinking about biochemistry, but the thermal engine nature of weather was crudely understood at the time...

Comment: @CosmasZachos yeah I get that but I am looking for a specific mention of the Sun-Earth system and biological organisms. I do not know if Clausius would have had enough abstraction to make this link.